# Have ::before stretch the full page width

Tags: html, css

**Problem**

I'm trying to stretch a `::before` element from the very left hand side of the page to the right hand side, even though the element it's attached to is centred and somewhat down the page (and thus does not know what the window size is etc).

Here's a working example of what I want:

http://codepen.io/robcampo/pen/dilCe

Problem with this is that I'm using static values to define the `width` and `left` position:

```
left: -9000px;
width: 99999px;
```

which isn't ideal. I understand this could be solved if I moved the element to another location on the page, but I need it next to the element it's attached to.

**Question**

Is there a clean way to make the `::before` content span the entire page width without using static values?

**Note**

- There is content above and below this element and it is far down the DOM tree away from the body
- I could solve using JS but I want a pure CSS solution

Answer (score 3):

If you remove `position: relative` from the parent element, you can easily do this.

You can center `.title` like this instead:

```
.title {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Then you can adjust the `::before` like this:

```
.title::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Bringing it all together: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLKGc

PS: Note that IE8 and before don't support the double-colon (CSS3) notation, so if you need to support IE8, make sure to use a single colon (CSS 2.1), which is supported by other browsers as well, and will probably be for a while.

Comment: Very good answer, thanks. However, I should have made it clearer that this content is buried deep down on the page (not my code), inside a number of different relatively positioned elements. Therefore, this solution won't work for me.

Comment: That's too bad. In that case, this solution indeed won't work. Your solution with large values might be the best solution, then, or maybe you can add a `:before` to another element.

Comment: Adding a ::before to another element is a good idea but, I want the before element to 'follow' the element it's attached to (e.g. as it pushes down the page when new content is added on top of it). I could solve using JS, but that's kinda hacky. 

Thanks for looking. I've edited the main question to make it clearer.